# How to install extensions manually on Windows?

Tags: extensions, install, cli

I can install extension manually using the 'mage' shell script on Linux - but is there an equivalent tool for Windows?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using xampp you should be able to run any PHP script as you would on Linux.
You might need to find out the path of the PHP executable though.

From the Windows console run the following

```
C:\xampp\php C:\xampp\htdocs\path\to\script.php
```